# Mongo db query nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to come up with a mongo query which would return me document and only fields (changes in nested document) for particular time range.

This is what I've tried but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Query:

```
   db.keywords.find(
        {
            $and :[{"_id" : "5374c7a7ac58b0d3b5e970fa"},{"field" : "keywordId"},{"adwordsChanges.timestamp" : {$gte:1400162491325, $lte:23918779329}}]
        })
```

Document:

```
{
   {
    "_id": ObjectId("5374c7a7ac58b0d3b5e970fa"),
    "documentchanges": [{
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "syncState",
        "old": null,
        "new": "OK"
        }, {
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "keywordId",
        "old": null,
        "new": NumberLong("23918779329")
        }, {
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "adGroupId",
        "old": null,
        "new": NumberLong("16972286472")
        }]
    }, {
    "_id": ObjectId("5374c7a7ac58b0d3b5e970f9"),
    "documentchanges": [{
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "syncState",
        "old": null,
        "new": "OK"
        }, {
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "keywordId",
        "old": null,
        "new": NumberLong("23918779329")
        }, {
        "timestamp": NumberLong("1400162491325"),
        "field": "adGroupId",
        "old": null,
        "new": NumberLong("16972286472")
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_id` find is looking for a string but your object contrains an ObjectId. Use this:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5374c7a7ac58b0d3b5e970fa")}
```

you are missing a `.` operator before `field`. use:

```
{"documentchanges.field" : "keywordId"}
```

There is also no tag `adwordsChanges` in your top level document, but you are reffering it here:

```
{"adwordsChanges.timestamp" : {$gte:1400162491325, $lte:23918779329}}
```

change this to `documentchanges` as well:

```
{"documentchanges.timestamp" : {$gte:1400162491325, $lte:23918779329}}
```

Also there is no timestamp lesser than or equal to 23918779329. Change the number.

Comment: Correct, I fixed that and it works it actually returns results. But what I am actually want to achieve - return only the subdocuments which are in that range. I don't want to see anything else. Is is possible to achieve in mongo?

Comment: what you mean is a projection: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projections